# Obtain image url path for this image inside flash element?

Tags: adobe-flash

Is there a way to determine the url of the image file found in the flash here?

https://logoizer.peaksystems.com/view/77700000-55d3-255a-1ed0901e27b4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the dev tools in Chrome (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). It lists all images under the resources tab. Specifically, have a look at the left column under Frames->Folder XYZ->Images or Other.

Another way would be to use Firebug in Firefox. Click on 'Network'->Images, reload the page and it lists you every loaded image.

Comment: chris couldn't have given you a simpler example. Try it. And lo and behold, surprise surprise, your answer doesn't work. The HTML you are displaying isn't going to show inside the flash is it. Chris wants to see inside it.

Comment: I had tried both versions before I posted. And lo and behold, surprise surprise, both of them worked. (http://marketing.peaksystems.com/imglib/mresjpg/21658/8881_30_z.jpg)

Comment: I don't see it but I believe you. I would remove my downvote but the system won't let me remove it unless perhaps you edit it, just a minor edit and it might let me remove the downvote.

Comment: Well, I've made it more explicit.

Comment: +1 i guess  it's there for me, and believe it's there for you, but here's a pic i don't see it http://i55.tinypic.com/svjo9c.jpg

Comment: I have to admit that it behaves strangely sometimes. Reloading the page helps very often. http://tinypic.com/r/144a9ex/7

Comment: Very nice. The resources tab. Should have thought of that! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I tried tineye

http://www.tineye.com/search/8ad8b3e6f831246d8934f594bb6c5be5e18e8ff2/

http://www.tineye.com/search/8ad8b3e6f831246d8934f594bb6c5be5e18e8ff2/

It could be one of these

http://www.hotdealsorg.com/review-of-liberty-bags-small-drawstring-backpack-8881.html
[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51SY6WITjlL.*AA160*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51SY6WITjlL._AA160_.jpg)

http://www.executivecateringdc.com/shoping/thousands-of-akc-great-backpack-strap-bright-yellow.html/
[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41J5rBMgMNL.*SL160*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41J5rBMgMNL._SL160_.jpg)